# Setting Focus to a silverlight 4 application in an MVC 3 view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, silverlight-4.0, focus

I'm having trouble with this. While it just means people have to click on the object to get it to respond, I think it looks unprofessional as hell.

Here is the view (including my n'th attempt):

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Show";
    //Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Empty.cshtml";
    Layout = "";

}

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.alerts.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#HDViewerSL').focus();
    });
</script>

<div id="silverlightControlHost" >
    <object  id='HDViewerSL' data="data:application/x-silverlight," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
        <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.60310.0"/>
        <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true"/>
        <param name="source" value="@ViewBag.HDViewSLXap"/>
        <param name="background" value="black"/>
        <param name="initParams" value="source=@ViewBag.ImagesUrl,id=@ViewBag.Id"/>

        <div style="text-align:center;font-family:Arial;margin-top:50px;">
        This page requires Silverlight 4.<br />
        <br />
        <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=4.0.60310.0" style="text-decoration: none;">
            <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style: none"/>
        </a>
        </div>
    </object>
    <iframe style='visibility:hidden;height:0;width:0;border:0px'></iframe>
</div>
```

In my Silverlight constructor, I have:

```
this.GotFocus += new RoutedEventHandler(HDViewer_GotFocus);
```

This event is never firing.

Anyone know how to get the focus set on the object?

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting "Invalid Operation Exception" with that code, but I had it in the constructor. At your suggestion @Avee I put it in the constructor instead of in the load event and there was no change. The problem was that I needed to add:

```
 <param name="enablehtmlaccess" value="true"/>
```

to the Silverlight object's parameters in the hosting page. (ref: http://weblogs.asp.net/albertpascual/archive/2009/04/13/silverlight-exception-the-dom-scripting-bridge-is-disabled.aspx)

Thanks!
David

Answer (score 0):

You can request the plugin to be focused from within you Silverlight application using `HtmlPage.Plugin.Focus();` The Loaded event of the MainPage is normally the right place to do this.